# iOS: animation between view controllers

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I can't find this anywhere. So, if you possess the info about it, please give me a link.

I have one view controller, I made a menu for a simple game. There are some buttons on it.
I have another view controller and there some buttons too.

The question is: 
"How I can do an animation of this buttons (hiding off the screen) after I choose one button that triggers a custom segue (without any animation) to another View Controller, which will run it's button animation(coming to the screen from a border of the screen)?"

I made this like this:

1) Theory: I make a IBAction for a menu button, then in this IBAction I call an animation method, which call a performSegueMethod:. After this in new VC in viewWillAppear method call a animation method (that almost equal method from source VC). All this works, but this don't look smooth. The problem with this animation occurs when destination VC replace source VC. There is some split second, when all looks static, and only after this animation starts. 
I don't know how to remove this destination VC lag. May be I must load a destination view before a segue? I tried to do this, but may be a made something wrong, or it's just don't help me.

2) Practice:

firstViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)newGameSegueButton {

[self menuSlideInDirection:@"CenterToLeft" performingSegueWithIdentifier:@"mode"];

}


-(void)menuSlideInDirection:(NSString *)direction performingSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)segueIdentifier
{


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{

    CGPoint newGameButtonCenter;
    newGameButtonCenter.x = directionIndex * 160;
    newGameButtonCenter.y = self.gameButtonSlide.center.y;
    self.gameButtonSlide.center = newGameButtonCenter;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
       //some animation too

    } completion:nil];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        //animation 

    } completion:nil];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
       //some animation too

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        if(segueIdentifier){
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueIdentifier sender:self];

        }
    }];





}];


}
```

Okay, then custom segue code is pretty simple:

```
-(void)perform
{


UIViewController *src = self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *dst = self.destinationViewController;

[src.navigationController pushViewController:dst animated:NO];


}
```

And my secondViewController.m:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];


[self menuSlideInDirection:@"RightToCenter" performingSegueWithIdentifier:nil];

}
```

menuSlideInDirection:@"RightToCenter" performingSegueWithIdentifier:nil in secondViewController identical to method with same name in firstView.

I'm looking for smooth animation of particular objects of destination view controller right after a segue.

May be a doing all wrong and there a another way to do this? (I only think of adding all view and all controls of destination VC to source VC and remove "destination VC" at all).

Hope, somebody can help me with this.

Comment: What's the segue transition you're doing to the new view controller?

Comment: Hmm I think I don't use any segue transition, as you can see in my perform method. I understood you right?

Comment: You are calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:`. Is this a push, modal? What kind of segue is it? Then again, it probably doesn't matter; I was just curious. You are correct that putting both views under the same VC will put the whole process under your control and enable you to make sure it is smooth. Otherwise you can do the hack that Roshan suggested.

Comment: @MattMc I use custom segue, hmm i don't know, honestly, push or a modal it is. I post a custom segue class perform method. I think, in fact it's a push segue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my question, I choose the way of putting two views under the same VC. Animation is smooth and it's look much better than using perform / viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing all first view controller's animations in `perform` method.

As for the second view controller's animations, I don't think there is any other 'good' way than doing it in `viewWillAppear` (although I would prefer `viewDidAppear`) since the outlets of the destination view controller are not set while performing the segue(they will be nil). In other words, you do not have a way to access your buttons, let alone animate them.

A hackish way would be to call `[segue.destinationViewController view]` before `perform` so that the destination view controller's view hierarchy is loaded and the outlets are set. Then perhaps, you may animate buttons in the destination view controller in `perform` before pushing it onto navigation stack.

Comment: How can I do all first VC animation in `perform` method if I haven't outlets to this buttons in custom segue class?

Comment: same question for the "hackish way", and destination VC outlets

Comment: Am I right, `[segue.destinationViewController view]` I must add to prepare for segue?

Comment: Forget to say, it's all don't work, as I want :( There is no noticeable changes, after this changes in code.